# Can't make child control overflow properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I got the following layout:

[image]

Just for reference here is the actual site with content omitted:

[image]

Now Red, Blue and Orange are all supposed to be fixed. The only part of the layout that should actually change at all, is the Green part. I have all the content of the green part wrapped in a div that's supposed to make this happen but I just can't figure it out.

I want it so that if Green overflows in Y then Green should be responsible for handling overflow instead of its parent. But currently the parent takes care of Overflow Y and for some reason Green takes care of Overflow X on it's own. I am not sure why this is. The parent of Green have this CSS:

```
.render-body {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: margin-left ease .25s;
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.render-body body {
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Now if I apply the CSS Rules for overflow here is what I get as a result (where the one in Green is the child's scrollbar, but the one to the right of it is the parent's scrollbar.):

[image]

I want the parent's scrollbar to go away so the child is responsible instead.

How would I achieve this?

---

Below are is CSS for Blue and Orange just in case you need it.

The Sidebar (Blue) got this:

```
.context-sidebar {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #eee;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    transition: left ease .25s;
}
```

The footer (Orange) got this:

```
.layout-footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The CSS for Red are just bootstrap classes:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-override" id="layout-navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox makes this kind of layout easy. Use a `column` layout for the main parent or `body`, then the main section will `flex-grow` to fill the space and be `flex` as well with it's left/right child sections as flex children with the green area set to `overflow-y: scroll`

```css
body {
  max-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  background: red;
}
footer {
  background: orange;
}
main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}
aside {
  background: blue;
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}
article {
  background: green;
  flex: 1 0 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<header>header
</header>

<main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <article>
    <p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p><p>foo</p>
  </article>
</main>

<footer>footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Well given the CSS I already have how'd I achieve this? Would I have to rewrite it all? I'm using bootstrap if that helps.

Comment: @Vipar you didn't post your complete code, I can't give you feedback about your existing code. I would have to guess at what classes apply to what elements and that your html is structured properly, and that isn't productive. You should be able to figure it out with my code, it's extremely simple. I made it that way on purpose so you can copy/paste it.

Comment: Well I just started over, using what you provided, so.